# Authorizing Swagger calls when using Istio Authorization

Tags: java, swagger, authorization, istio

I'm moving my Spring Boot application from Spring Security authorization to Istio AuthorizationPolicy based one. My Spring app exposes Swagger API docs and previously I could authorize my Swagger calls.

Is there any good way to do it with Istio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up generating Authorization tokens with Postman and pasting them into Swagger. Slightly less convenient but works